# Does Realm work with Cocoa Binding in edit operation?

Tags: macos, cocoa, realm, cocoa-bindings

I am using `NSOutlineView` and bind to an array of Realm Object. It works for showing the attributes using data binding.

When I try to edit the item, it throws the following:

```
2015-12-28 12:21:13.433 My_Mac_App[87665:3922875] Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.
2015-12-28 12:21:13.436 My_Mac_App[87665:3922875] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff830d4e32 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9303e4fa objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Realm                               0x00000001002a9127 _ZL27RLMVerifyInWriteTransactionP13RLMObjectBase + 103
    3   Realm                               0x000000010029f6bd _ZL11RLMSetValueP13RLMObjectBasemP8NSString + 29
    4   Realm                               0x00000001002a9c8c _ZZZL13RLMMakeSetterIU8__strongP8NSStringS2_EPFvvEP11RLMPropertyEUb1_ENKUlvE_clEv + 44
    5   Realm                               0x00000001002a6d20 _ZL13RLMWrapSetterIZZL13RLMMakeSetterIU8__strongP8NSStringS3_EPFvvEP11RLMPropertyEUb1_EUlvE_EvP13RLMObjectBaseS2_OT_ + 176
    6   Realm                               0x00000001002a6c30 ___ZL13RLMMakeSetterIU8__strongP8NSStringS2_EPFvvEP11RLMProperty_block_invoke_2 + 96
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff8abd5674 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 424
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8abf8276 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 287
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff956b4640 -[NSView setValue:forKeyPath:] + 398
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff956f0e4a -[NSBinder _setValue:forKeyPath:ofObject:mode:validateImmediately:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:error:] + 411
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff956f0c58 -[NSBinder setValue:forBinding:error:] + 248
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff95b9838b -[NSValueBinder _applyObjectValue:forBinding:canRecoverFromErrors:handleErrors:typeOfAlert:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:] + 220
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff95b986d6 -[NSValueBinder applyDisplayedValueHandleErrors:typeOfAlert:canRecoverFromErrors:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:error:] + 566
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff95b98861 -[NSValueBinder _applyDisplayedValueIfHasUncommittedChangesWithHandleErrors:typeOfAlert:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:error:] + 117
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff9576a5e2 -[NSValueBinder validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:] + 484
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff9576a3d7 -[_NSBindingAdaptor _validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:bindingAdaptor:] + 162
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff9576a316 -[_NSBindingAdaptor validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:] + 246
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff955ce6a4 -[NSTextField textShouldEndEditing:] + 374
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff955ba950 -[NSTextView(NSSharing) resignFirstResponder] + 493
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff954af01f -[NSWindow _realMakeFirstResponder:] + 228
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff954aeee7 -[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:] + 123
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff95bb5109 -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 5518
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff95bb6411 -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 212
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff955fbb8d -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 517
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff9557bb27 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2540
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff953e2d9a -[NSApplication run] + 796
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff953abfbe NSApplicationMain + 1176
    28  My_Mac_App                          0x000000010004fc37 main + 87
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff903715ad start + 1
)
```

Is it possible to use data binding, and able to edit?

Is there any other practice in using it?

Comment: Have you ever been able to find a suitable solution for this issue?

Comment: @dwbrito I moved out from using NSOutlineView. In other cases, I try to use the data source APIs instead of cocoa bindings

Comment: I'm currently trying to create a write transaction before updating the field, with a binding. Will let you know I can work it out @Harry Ng

Answer (score 0):

Realm doesn't offer dedicated support for Cocoa Bindings. But as they are based on KVC/KVO, which is supported, you should be fine at least for standalone objects. If you want to work with attached / persisted objects, you would need to ensure yourself, that those modifications are made within write transactions.

I'm not sure where the best place would be for that, but the stacktrace should give some ideas. You could try to react on `-[NSTextField textShouldEndEditing:]` before it delegates to `_NSBindingAdaptor` or try to method swizzle further down the call hierarchy. Beside that you could have proxy objects delegating to the `RLMObject` and starting a write transaction if necessary.

Alternatively, depending on when you need to propagate the results of your write transactions, you could start a write transaction earlier on when presenting the view and committing it e.g. when the user hits `Save` in the UI.

Comment: How could I make sure they are within write transactions? as the save operation is called by cocoa binding.

Answer (score 0):

Realm is overriding your properties with NSKeyValueCoding, so you can just override theirs implementation and just before each set call begin and commit transaction. Or in more safe way, use transaction just when you prefix some property with "realm" (realmValue).

```
@interface DataObject : RLMObject

@end

@implementation DataObject

- (id) valueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key hasPrefix:@"realm"]) {
        return [super valueForKey:[self _transformKey:key]];
    } else {
        return [super valueForKey:key];
    }
}

- (void) setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key hasPrefix:@"realm"]) {
        [self.realm beginWriteTransaction];

        [super setValue:value forKey:[self _transformKey:key]];

        NSError *error;
        [self.realm commitWriteTransaction:&error];
        if (error) {
            DDLogError(@"Failed to commint transaction: %@", error);
        }
    } else {
        [super setValue:value forKey:key];
    }
}

- (NSString *) _transformKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSString *newKey = [key substringFromIndex:5];
    return [newKey stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:[[newKey substringToIndex:1] lowercaseString]];
}

@end
```